# Connecting multiple clients to a client host using WebRTC javascript

Tags: webrtc

Hi i am having troubles figuring out how to connect multiple clients together. I can connect 2 clients with no problem but cannot connect more than 2.

I understand that each client needs to be connected to every other client. So i want to create a lobby which can hold up to 6 people. So far my lobby only works with 2.

My question is this. Do i create an array of webkitRTCPeerConnection objects?
like so...

```
 myConnection[ii] = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

or do i have 1 connection per client that manages all the peer connections?
like so...

```
 myConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

The answer to this question will set me on the right path here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is the answer, Make individual connections to each client so create an array of connection objects.